# React site, trying to embed app, but I can't figure out how to integrate into a component (works on the static page)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, embed

I'm trying to embed the following onto my react site in a specific component/page. When I put the code on the static html page it works beautifully, but it isn't working out when I try to place it onto the component.

The main error I'm getting is saying that chrome won't allow `document.write` from an external script or something along those lines. *I wish I still had the error message, but I've been trying different things and in a fit of frustration deleted it all last night. (Great strategy, I know.)* **I was able to retrieve the errors, please see at the bottom for details.**

```
<div id="fTelnetContainer" class="fTelnetContainer"></div>
<script>document.write('<script src="//embed-v2.ftelnet.ca/js/ftelnet-loader.norip.xfer.js?v=' + (new Date()).getTime() + '"><\/script>');</script>
<script>
    var Options = new fTelnetOptions();
    Options.BareLFtoCRLF = false;
    Options.BitsPerSecond = 57600;
    Options.ConnectionType = 'telnet';
    Options.Emulation = 'ansi-bbs';
    Options.Enter = '\r';
    Options.Font = 'CP437';
    Options.ForceWss = false;
    Options.Hostname = 'mysite.com';
    Options.LocalEcho = false;
    Options.NegotiateLocalEcho = true;
    Options.Port = 1234;
    Options.ProxyHostname = 'proxy-us-ga.ftelnet.ca';
    Options.ProxyPort = 80;
    Options.ProxyPortSecure = 443;
    Options.ScreenColumns = 80;
    Options.ScreenRows = 25;
    Options.SendLocation = true;
    var fTelnet = new fTelnetClient('fTelnetContainer', Options);
</script>
```

I'm not looking for anyone to do this for me, but if you could provide a tip, point me to some documentation, or any hint whatsoever I would be eternally grateful.

This embed is coming from the following site by the way: **http://embed-v2.ftelnet.ca/**

**EDIT**

I'm still working on this, so I tried to get back the error messages and here is what happened:

```
(index):46 A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, http://embed-v2.ftelnet.ca/js/ftelnet-loader.norip.xfer.js?v=1599169227014, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.

A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://ftelnet.ca/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

ftelnet-loader.norip.xfer.js?v=1599169227014:1 A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, http://embed-v2.ftelnet.ca/ftelnet/ftelnet.norip.xfer.min.js?v=2019-08-31, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.
```

**EDIT2**
This is my component at the moment:

```
class Home extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    document.write("<script src='//embed-v2.ftelnet.ca/js/ftelnet-loader.norip.xfer.js?v=" + (new Date()).getTime() + "'></script>" +
        "<script>" +
        "window.onload(function() {" +
        "var Options = new fTelnetOptions();" +
        "Options.BareLFtoCRLF = false;" +
        "Options.BitsPerSecond = 57600;" +
        "Options.ConnectionType = 'telnet';" +
        "Options.Emulation = 'ansi-bbs';" +
        "Options.Enter = '\r';" +
        "Options.Font = 'CP437';" +
        "Options.ForceWss = false;" +
        "Options.Hostname = 'mysite.com';" +
        "Options.LocalEcho = true;" +
        "Options.NegotiateLocalEcho = true;" +
        "Options.Port = 1234;" +
        "Options.ProxyHostname = 'proxy-us-ga.ftelnet.ca';" +
        "Options.ProxyPort = 80;" +
        "Options.ProxyPortSecure = 443;" +
        "Options.ScreenColumns = 80;" +
        "Options.ScreenRows = 25;" +
        "Options.SendLocation = true;" +
        "var fTelnet = new fTelnetClient('fTelnetContainer', Options);" +
        "});" +
         + "</script>");

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h1>TELNET TIME</h1>
      <div id="fTelnetContainer" className="fTelnetContainer"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

*This also throws the error, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue when I needed to use PayPal scripts (they do not support importing ES6 modules).

First of all, `document.write` will not work for you because by the time the `componentDidMount` is invoked, the document is already fully loaded. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write. Therefore calling this again - should the `write` function push through - will erase everything in the document and write a new one.

To solve your issue, here is what I did: on your initial html document, example `index.html`, this is where I included your script to load the source codes needed and I assigned the fTelnetOptions object to a window property since you instantiate this later on:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    document.write(
        '<script src="//embed-v2.ftelnet.ca/js/ftelnet-loader.norip.xfer.js?v=' +
            new Date().getTime() +
        '"><\/script>'
    );
    window.fTelnetOptions = fTelnetOptions;
  </script>
</head>
```

Back on your component, do what you have to to initialize the telnet when the component mounts - see the window.fTelnetOptions that we instantiated:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var Options = new window.fTelnetOptions();
    Options.BareLFtoCRLF = false;
    Options.BitsPerSecond = 57600;
    Options.ConnectionType = "telnet";
    Options.Emulation = "ansi-bbs";
    Options.Enter = "\r";
    Options.Font = "CP437";
    Options.ForceWss = false;
    Options.Hostname = "mysite.com";
    Options.LocalEcho = true;
    Options.NegotiateLocalEcho = true;
    Options.Port = 1234;
    Options.ProxyHostname = "proxy-us-ga.ftelnet.ca";
    Options.ProxyPort = 80;
    Options.ProxyPortSecure = 443;
    Options.ScreenColumns = 80;
    Options.ScreenRows = 25;
    Options.SendLocation = true;
    var fTelnet = new window.fTelnetClient("fTelnetContainer", Options);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>TELNET TIME</h1>
        <div id="fTelnetContainer" className="fTelnetContainer"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

[image: Edit confident-vaughan-4t225]

---

At this point I am not sure how well this will work with client-side-routing. Refer to my scripts below if you encounter that the fTelnetOptions property in window object is lost when routing:

```
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = `your_script_url`;
script.async = true;
document.body.appendChild(script);

script.onload = () => {
    // do your instantiation & logic here
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working fairly well for now. I'm still flooded with warnings in the console, but I think this is probably the best way to handle it at the moment. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. If you have access to the scripts you are trying to include, I suggest your refactor it into a module so you can import it easily in your components